# How to know if a System.Diagnostic.Process has exited due to timeout?

Tags: c#

Right now I have something like

```
void MyMethod
{
   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit(10); // here we set a timeout of 10 seconds

   //now here I'd like to check whether the process exited normally or
   //due to timeout. How do I do this?
   // Important: I wanna know whether it timed out or not, not if it has exited or not.
}
```

How can I tell if the process exited before the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the boolean result on `process.WaitForExit` to see if it was exited due to just the time out. If you wanted to see if there was an error you can check [Process.ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

> I wanna know whether it timed out or not, not if it has exited or not.

If `process.WaitForExit` returns true the process exited on its own. If false the process is still running and the timeout has expired, this (the waiting and return to execution) does **not** kill the process.

> Do I have to kill it manually or just doing a using will kill it do to IDisposable?

You should call [Kill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx). You should also wrap the process in a `using` block so the resources are disposed.

```
void MyMethod
{
   using(Process process = new Process()) {
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
     process.Start();
     if(!process.WaitForExit(10000)) // here we set a timeout of 10 seconds (time is in milliseconds)
         process.Kill(); // if you really want to stop the process, its still running here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to kill it manually or just doing a using will kill it do to IDisposable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Damieh - answered your question above in my answer. You should call Kill but you should also wrap your process in a using block so that it is disposed after you use it.

Comment: `WaitForExit(10000)` if you want to wait up to 10 seconds: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx "...Instructs the Process component to wait the specified number of milliseconds for the associated process to exit..."

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - good catch. Thats what I get for copy/paste without checking the parameters first. I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Igor! =)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - by the way, it looks like I was not the only one that made that mistake :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Process.HasExited Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) .

> Gets a value indicating whether the associated process has been terminated.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> A value of true for HasExited indicates that the associated process has terminated, either normally or abnormally. You can request or force the associated process to exit by calling CloseMainWindow or Kill. If a handle is open to the process, the operating system releases the process memory when the process has exited, but retains administrative information about the process, such as the handle, exit code, and exit time. To get this information, you can use the ExitCode and ExitTime properties. These properties are populated automatically for processes that were started by this component. The administrative information is released when all the Process components that are associated with the system process are destroyed and hold no more handles to the exited process.
>
> A process can terminate independently of your code. If you started the process using this component, the system updates the value of HasExited automatically, even if the associated process exits independently.

The time out parameter of WaitForExit only says how much time your code will wait for the process to exit. However, it will not kill the process itself.

> This method (WaitForExit) instructs the Process component to wait a finite amount of time for the process to exit. If the associated process does not exit by the end of the interval because the request to terminate is denied, false is returned to the calling procedure."
>   Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx

```
void MyMethod
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit(10); // here we set a timeout of 10 seconds

        //now here I'd like to check whether the process exited normally or
        //due to timeout.
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Also wrap the process in a using block, as it implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I tried this, but if it timed out then it will have exited anyways =(. I wanna know whether it timed out or not, not if it has exited or not.

Comment: The time out parameter of WaitForExit only says how much time your code will wait for the process to exit. However, it will not kill the process itself. "This method instructs the Process component to wait a finite amount of time for the process to exit. If the associated process does not exit by the end of the interval because the request to terminate is denied, false is returned to the calling procedure." Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx

Comment: `WaitForExit(10000)` if you want to wait up to 10 seconds: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx "...Instructs the Process component to wait the specified number of milliseconds for the associated process to exit..."

Answer (score 1):

```
process.WaitForExit(10);
```

returns true if the associated process has exited; otherwise, false.
In other words, if the associated process does not exit by the end of the interval, false is returned to the calling procedure.

as says in https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So it will return false if it timed out? It's not very well-explained =(

Comment: If the associated process does not exit by the end of the interval, false is returned to the calling procedure

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `Process.WaitForExit` will tell you whether the process exited before the timeout:

```
void MyMethod
{
   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   process.Start();
   var processExited = process.WaitForExit(10); // here we set a timeout of 10 seconds

   //now here I'd like to check whether the process exited normally or
   //due to timeout. How do I do this?
   // Important: I wanna know whether it timed out or not, not if it has exited or not.
   if (processExited)
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of time before and after `process.WaitForExit(10);` and compare it to your time out (10s here). This way you know the exact time of running the process which is not achievelable by other methods.